# What GLib type should a{ss} map to when using GSettings?

Tags: dictionary, glib, gsettings, gvariant

I have a gsettings schema with a key of type `a{ss}`. I would like to bind said key to a property on an object. I have successfully used `g_settings_bind` and `g_settings_bind_with_mapping` with other keys but I don't know what type to map this key to. The `GVariant` is an array of dictionaries with key string and value string, but what accual glib type is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`g_settings_bind_with_mapping()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html#g-settings-bind-with-mapping), since `a{ss}` is [not supported by `g_settings_bind()`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/2.56.0/gio/gsettings-mapping.c#L328). `a{ss}` is a dictionary mapping strings to strings, and I would probably represent it in GLib as a [`GHashTable`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) mapping strings to strings.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't `a{ss}` contain duplicate keys while in `GHashTable` keys must be unique?

Comment: You are wrong. `a{ss}` is a dictionary in D-Bus terms, which is defined as not accepting duplicate keys (https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#container-types). You may be thinking of `a(ss)` which is an array of tuples, and has no such restrictions.